# Should closing questions by review count against the vote close count?

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close, voting-limits

AFAIK I have about 40 or 50 close counts per day, right? Now when I do reviewing "Close Votes" I think that at least 70%-80% of the questions being flagged for closed, are really to be closed. So when you do the review, you are left with something between 10-20 close votes.

Now considering the overwhelming number of bad questions I was wondering if this really makes sense. When you consequently do the review, it means that you run out of closing votes pretty soon.

So I was wondering whether it wouldn't make sense to differ between a vote close and a review close. Another side effect is that, if you run out of vote close you can still review, but it doesn't really make sense anymore, as you can not close bad questions anyway.

So in that case, either the review queue should be disabled, or it shouldn't count as a close vote.

Comment: why should the review queue be disabled?!?! Just don't review questions on the close-votes-queue and spend your daily close votes on other questions.

Comment: When you review, then it is inevitable to close questions, so it doesn't really make sense to allow reviewing, but not allowing to take the appropriate action. In such a case you can only accept (bad) or skip the question (waste of time).